# How to use a secondary account to pay for primary accounts cpu/ram using eosjs java script library

Tags: eosjs, javascript, node

I am trying to use a secondary account to pay for cpu/ram for the primary accounts eosio.tokens how do I do that using eosjs library

My current action looks like this

```
actions: [{
    account: 'eosio.token',
    name: 'transfer',
    authorization: [{
      actor: 'lionster1011',
      permission: 'active',
    }],
    data: {
      from: 'lionster1011',
      to: 'lionster1010',
      quantity: '10.0000 EOS',
      memo: 'EOS-TRANSFER',
    },
  }]
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authorize the transaction with signatures for both accounts. 1. The ressource-paying-account and 2. the acting account.

Assuming that lionstester1010 should pay for the transaction but lionstester1011 is the acting account/the sender of the token:

```
actions: [{
   account: 'eosio.token',
   name: 'transfer',
   authorization: [{
      actor: 'lionster1010',
      permission: 'active'},{
      actor: 'lionster1011',
      permission: 'active',
}],
data: {
   from: 'lionster1011',
   to: 'lionster1010',
   quantity: '10.0000 EOS',
   memo: 'EOS-TRANSFER',
},
}]
```

Self-explanatory you need the keys of both accounts to sign the tx.